# Where is `unshare` defined on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I am trying to use the `unshare` system call, however I am unable to locate the header where it is defined. I tried:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
```

But to no result (The function isn't there, I looked at the header myself). Which header should I include?

Comment: Then it's probably in some header that's included by `<sched.h>` itself.

Comment: @zwol, withdrawn.

Comment: Usually I just `grep -r unshare /usr/include`

Answer (score 2):

I have tried and failed to reproduce the statement in the question: My test program builds without issues.

I looked up the `unshare(2)` man page and found

```
SYNOPSIS
       #define _GNU_SOURCE
       #include <sched.h>

       int unshare(int flags);
```

so I wrote a small test program

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>

int main(void)
{
  unshare(123);
  return 0;
}
```

which I then built with all warnings enabled and treated as errors:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -o unshare-ex unshare-ex.c
$ _
```

without any problems.

So I rebuilt the program with

```
$ gcc -g -O2 -save-temps=obj -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -o unshare-ex unshare-ex.c
$ _
```

and took a look at `unshare-ex.i` to trace the include files. As it turns out, `/usr/include/sched.h` eventually includes `/usr/include/bits/sched.h` which contains the definition of the `unshare()` function which expands to

```
extern int unshare (int __flags) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__));
```

but is written in `/usr/include/bits/sched.h` as

```
extern int unshare (int __flags) __THROW;
```

I am not sure what the problem is here.

FWIW, both `/usr/include/sched.h` and `/usr/include/bits/sched.h` are shipped as part of the `glibc-headers-x86-2.35-15.fc36.noarch` package here.

Comment: I suppose OP's original "problem" was that they couldn't find the actual specification in `bits/sched.h`, not that something wasn't working.

Answer (score -3):

Apparently instead of

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

It should be

```c
#define __USE_GNU
```

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's a little too strongly worded.  It is perfectly fine to use `__FILE__`, `__STDC_VERSION__`, etc. for their documented purpose.

Comment: @AggelosT If `__USE_GNU` appeared to do something useful when `_GNU_SOURCE` didn't, that _probably_ means you defined `_GNU_SOURCE` in the wrong place.  The feature selection macros must be defined before you include _any_ header file.  See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html

Comment: Fair enough, @zwol.  Correction: it should never be anything involving *defining* identifiers whose names have leading double underscores.  Such definitions produce undefined behavior in your program. (Reference: C17 7.1.3 and corresponding sections in earlier C standards)